# Match string using Spring @RequestMapping path expression

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to match a string using the expression language used for the `path` (or `value`) variable in the `@RequestMapping` annotation? For example, given the string

```
/api/foo/bar/1
```

the expression

```
/api/foo/bar/{id}
```

should match this string (a test should be available that returns a boolean `true` if the expression matches the given string), and if possible, the captured portion of the string (namely, `{id}` capturing `1`) should also be available.

Essentially, I am looking to use the same mechanism that Spring internally uses for `@RequestMapping` to check if a URL path (a combination of the context path and path information) matches in the expression language as `@RequestMapping`. I am doing this matching with a Spring security filter.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This might be a wrong approach. Why are you going to do that exactly?

Comment: Within a security filter, I have created hooks for each type of HTTP method (i.e. `onSuccessfulPost`). Within these hooks, I have a context object that I want to check to see if it matches a given URL. For example, `context.matchesPath("/api/foo/bar/{id}");`. My goal was to match the URL using an expression identical to that of the Spring `@RequestMapping` so that if someone comes along, they see identical notation. Plus, that expression language captures a lot of information in a succinct manner (i.e. another developer can gather that I'm trying to match the given URL ending with an ID).

Comment: That explains what you want to do. But what exactly is your final use case? I currently don't have an idea why you want to match the url after a successful request.

Comment: I'm looking to perform certain logic based on the request URL. For example, if a POST is completed using the `/api/foo/bar/{id}`, I need to log that "Foo Bar 1 was created." Given that the security filter has hooks for the type of HTTP method used, I now have to decide how to handle the logging for the request based on the URL (or, more precisely, the path after the servlet path, as is used in `@RequestMapping`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use aspects for this. With aspects, you simply can annotate a manager interface method with e.g. `@LogOnSuccess`.

```
public class UserManager{
    ...
    @LogOnSuccess
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto newUser)
        return userManager.createUser(newUser);
    }
}
```

Using a `@AfterReturning` point cut will only invoke a custom action bound to the annotation, if no exception occurred during the method call. This way you only log successful requests. Also it's very easy to use and highly readable.

There are a lot of good tutorials about this: e.g. [Spring AOP Example Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2583/spring-aop-example-tutorial-aspect-advice-pointcut-joinpoint-annotations)

Comment: I agree that AOP would fit this use case well, but I am currently constrained to use a Spring filter, since default logging is provided. For example, the current filter logs all GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE calls (i.e. `POST performed on /api/foo/bar/1`). I am looking to override the default to provide a more detailed message that includes information obtained from a DAO. For example, `Foo Bar with name <some name> and ID 1 was created.`

Comment: IMHO, you need to separate these as these are two different events. `POST performed on /api/foo/bar/1` is the log event of an incoming request before even reaching any business logic. Usually done by the web server. `Foo Bar with name <some name> and ID 1 was created.` is a log event that documents you back end events of your business logic and also should happen if it was invoked internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.springframework.http.server.PathContainer;
import org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPattern;
import org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class PathPatternTest {

    @Test
    public void testTrue() {
        Assert.assertTrue(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}", "/users/h49IB7A2B8r3eSg4q"));
        Assert.assertTrue(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}", "/users/123456"));
        Assert.assertTrue(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}", "/users/xxx?32321321"));
        Assert.assertTrue(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}", "/users/1234"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFalse() {
        Assert.assertFalse(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}/{token}", "/user/h49IB7A2B8r3eSg4q"));
        Assert.assertFalse(isPatternMatchUri("/users/{userId}", "/users/xxxx/12121"));
        Assert.assertFalse(isPatternMatchUri("/{userId}", "/usrs/xxx/WWQQS?"));
    }

    /***
     * is pattern match the request uri.
     */
    public boolean isPatternMatchUri(String pattern, String url) {
        PathPatternParser pathPatternParser = new PathPatternParser();
        PathPattern pathPattern = pathPatternParser.parse(pattern);
        PathContainer pathContainer = PathContainer.parsePath(url);
        return pathPattern.matches(pathContainer);
    }
}
```

Comment: please describe your answer how to solve the problem